# Java Arraylist change one attribute value in all objects at the same time

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a model with this attribute

```
public class Audit extends BaseModel implements Comparable {
@Column
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("audit_id")
private int id;

@Column
@SerializedName("address_line_1")
private String addressLine1;

@Column
@SerializedName("address_line_2")
private String addressLine2;

@Column
@SerializedName("city_name")
private String city;

@Column
@SerializedName("zip_code")
private String zipcode;

@Column
@SerializedName("company_id")
private int companyId;

@Column
@SerializedName("company_name")
private String companyName;

@Column
@SerializedName("loc_name")
private String location;

@Column
@SerializedName("inspection_date_time")
private OffsetDateTime inspectionTime;

@Column
@SerializedName("inspection_number")
private String inspectionNumber;

@Column(defaultValue = "0")
private int auditStatus;

@Column(defaultValue = "0")
private int userId;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getAddressLine1() {
    return addressLine1;
}

public String getAddressLine2() {
    return addressLine2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public int getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public OffsetDateTime getInspectionTime() {
    return inspectionTime;
}

public String getInspectionNumber() {
    return inspectionNumber;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
}

public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setInspectionTime(OffsetDateTime inspectionTime) {
    this.inspectionTime = inspectionTime;
}

public void setInspectionNumber(String inspectionNumber) {
    this.inspectionNumber = inspectionNumber;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Object audits) {
    int result = -1;
    if (audits instanceof Audit) {
        Audit audit = (Audit) audits;
        if (this.getInspectionTime().isEqual(audit.getInspectionTime())) {
            result = 0;
        } else if 
 (this.getInspectionTime().isAfter(audit.getInspectionTime())) {
            result = 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public int getAuditStatus() {
    return auditStatus;
}

public void setAuditStatus(int auditStatus) {
    this.auditStatus = auditStatus;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

In here I get all values to Arraylist using this model

```
List<Audit> auditList
```

My list is "auditList", It contains Audit objects, In this auditList I want to chnge one attribute 
for ex: I want to change userId value to "3" in all objects, How can I do it once, Is there any solution please Help Me

Comment: Your `compareTo` method is wrong btw.

Comment: @azro No, it's wrong. There's a specific contract for the method, and that implementation violates it. Nothing to do with attribute checking. You might want to [read it too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: @Kayaman then what is the best way to write compareTo

Comment: Correctly. As explained in the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Java 8 Stream :

`auditList.stream().forEach(elt -> elt.setUserId(3));`

It corresponds to :

```
for (Audit aud : auditList) {
    aud.setUserId(3);
}
```

Comment: foreach --> forEach

Answer (score 3):

You will need to iterate through all elements and update

```
for (Audit aud : auditList) {

    aud.setUserId(3);

}
```

If you want it on one line then

```
for (Audit aud : auditList) aud.setUserId(3);
```

Comment: Thanks, Without Iterate Is there any solution

Comment: Not that I can think of